# I have installed flash player but it's not working

Tags: 14.04, firefox, flash

I have install flash player for my firefox but it show me error

```
   To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 11.1.0 or greater is installed.
```

Comment: Go to the add-ins page and then the plugins tab. Confirm the Flash version number and make sure it shows "Enabled". Also confirm Firefox is the current version.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've always installed Flash Player on Firefox:

1. Go [here](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect)
2. Select ".tar.gz for other Linux"
3. Click "Download now"
4. Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
5. Run `mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins/`
6. Run `mkdir ~/Downloads/extracted/`
7. Run `tar xf ~/Downloads/install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/extracted/`
8. Run `mv ~/Downloads/extracted/libflashplayer.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/`
9. Run `rm -rf ~/Downloads/extracted/`
10. Run `exit`
11. Restart Firefox

Comment: Didn't worked for me...